# How to store recordings for each channel

Tags: twilio, twilio-api, twilio-click-to-call, twilio-functions

I am following following blog to click to call.
https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/click-to-call-java-spring

I am able to place call and record too. But how can we store recording for each channel ?

Can someone please help.?

callCreator.setRecordingChannels("5"); or
callCreator.setRecordingChannels("dual");
does not help

Here is the complete class

```
public class TwilioLine {
    private String twilioNumber;
    private TwilioRestClient restClient;

    public TwilioLine(TwilioRestClient restClient, String twilioNumber) {
        this.restClient = restClient;
        this.twilioNumber = twilioNumber;
    }

    public void call(final String phoneNumber, final String responseUrl)  {
        try {
            CallCreator callCreator = new CallCreator(new PhoneNumber(phoneNumber), new PhoneNumber(twilioNumber), new URI(responseUrl));
            callCreator.setRecord(true);
            callCreator.setSendDigits("8245719056");
            callCreator.setRecordingChannels("5");
            callCreator.create(restClient);
        } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
            throw new CallException(e);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to store recordings in separate channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46417096/unable-to-store-recordings-in-separate-channel)

Comment: Hey, it doesn't matter if you try to do this in Java or JavaScript, Twilio will only record 2 channels at a time. You need to use the parameter `dual` and connect the two calls together with a `<Dial>`. It doesn't work on conferences.